# Próximos Múltiplos de 5 - retornar uma array

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho que implementar uma função que recebe dois números como parâmetro e retorna a partir do valor passado um `array` com os próximos múltiplos de 5

Porém preciso de tenha também o retorno "20,25,30"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Poderia colocar o código dentro da pergunta de maneira textual? [saiba o motivo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7816/postar-mensagem-de-erro-como-imagem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nessa função eu descubro o múltiplo de 5 mais próximo do nosso valor inicial, com isso eu faço um laço `for` preenchendo um array com os valores que eu espero, que no caso são valores múltiplos de 5.

```js
function proximoMultiploDe5(valorInicial, quantidade) {
  let meuArray = [];
  const multiploDe5 = Math.ceil(valorInicial/5)*5;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
    meuArray.push(multiploDe5 + (i * 5))
  }

  return meuArray;
}

console.log(proximoMultiploDe5(13, 3)); // saída: [15,20,25]
```

Comment: deu certooo, muito obrigado mano

Comment: Disponha e bons estudos, você consegue!! 